# PhpMyAdmin direct console (like SQLyog)

Tags: phpmyadmin, console

We now have to use PhpMyAdmin for all database access but I've always used software like SQLyog or the database console within PhpStorm.

I'm finding PhpMyAdmin to be very clumsy and it slows down my workflow. Is there any way to get PhpMyAdmin to mimic SQLyog or PhpStorm? Is there an API for console-like access?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know SQLyog or PhpStorm at all, but if you're looking for console-like access there's a small "Console" button in the bottom corner of the phpMyAdmin screen which brings up a sort of console which may help you. Also the SQL tab gives you an interface to directly enter SQL queries; though it's not really in a console-like way.